# Why is a set is decidable iff it is the domain of a computable function

Tags: functions, logic, set-theory, formal-languages, turing-machines

I'm studying three paradigms of computability theory: Godel's, Turing's, and von Neumann's. In the first two, it is given as a theorem that $f$ is a computable function iff its domain $S$ is decidable (i.e. its characteristic function is computable). My textbook, which was written by professors at my local university, states that this property does not hold in von Neumman's paradigm.

Regardless of the paradigms involved, the statement does not make sense to me. Take for example a Turing machine $M$ which computes a function $f : S \to L$. If some input $x \in S$ is given we can decide that $x \in S$ because the machine would halt. However, if $x \not\in S$ we would "wait forever"; this is, we could never truly decide that $x \not\in S$. Why would $S$ be computable iff it is the domain of a computable function then?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand the claim that domains of computable partial functions are decidable. They are in general only r.e. What textbook are you using?

Comment: It was written by my professor, it is not a commercial or publicly available one..

Comment: Can you quote carefully the relevant part? This is such a basic point I suspect there is a subtlety somewhere that's been dropped.

Comment: I'll translate the relevant theorems.

Comment: @lafinur:  The domain of a total recursive function is all the input domain, either $\Bbb{N}$, or tuples of $\Bbb{N}$ or strings over some alphabet.  It always halts even if the output is to say 'malformed input'.  A partial recursive function is one that may or may not halt, and then the domain is the set of all inputs on which it halts - is a recursively enumerable set.  It's a matter of terminology whether they're referring to a total recursive function or partial recursive function.

Comment: @ChadK Thanks for the input. You say that if $f$ is partial recursive then it may or may not halt, and that the domain is the set of inputs for which it halts. But this requires us to have a way to know in advance whether $f$ will halt for a given input. I don't see why this is necessarily so. If we cannot know this *in advance*, how can we decide whether an element is in the domain or not?

Comment: @lafinur: It doesn't require us to have a way to know in advance whether $f$ will halt for a given input.  We don't know precisely the inputs on which it halts.  It's a definition that the set of inputs on which it halts is the domain.  The domain is recursively enumerable.  If the domain is recursive then the computation machine for the function can be modified to always halt and announce 'malformed input'.

Comment: I appreciate the input, don't take me wrong. But it you are just restating the property that I claimed not to understand, without providing elucidation. I understand that the domain is defined as the set of inputs for which the machine halts. But you immediately add: The domain is recursively enumerable. My question is: Why?

Comment: @lafinur:  Your question was whether the domain is recursive, not whether it's recursively enumerable.  Those are not the same.

Comment: What? My question was "Why would  be computable iff it is the domain of a computable function then?". The word "recursive" did not even appear in my question.

Comment: @lafinur:  Computable set = recursive set.  I posted an answer.

Comment: What does your book say is different between von Neumann's paradigm and the other two? This is not a standard distinction as far as I know.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question: the book is at best misleading or at worst plain wrong (probably the latter).

Answer (score 0):

The discussion is a about a model of computation in which the program takes an input which is either a string of characters in some finite alphabet, or a natural number or a tuple of natural numbers.  A run of the program leads to one of the following results

- Accept, optionally producing some output.
- Reject.
- Not halt.

The function that the program computes is called partial recursive if all of the results above are permitted.  Its domain is the set of all inputs on which it accepts.

If the program provably halts on all inputs, the function it computes is called a total recursive function.  Its domain is the set of all inputs on which it accepts.

A subset $S$ of the input space (i.e. strings, etc.) is called recursive if there's a program that accepts for all inputs in $S$ (any optional output is ignored), rejects for all inputs not in $S$.  Such a program always halts.

A subset $S$ of the input space is called recursively enumerable if there's a program that accepts for all inputs in $S$.  For other inputs it either rejects or not halts.

Given a program that computes a partial recursive function, its domain is a recursively enumberable set.  This is by definition, because the given program itself accepts for all inputs in its domain.  The fact it may produce additional output (as a function) is ignored.  If the input is not in its domain, it either rejects or not-halts.

Given a program that computes a total recursive function, its domain is a recursive set.  Again, this is by definition.  The given program satisfies the requirements for showing its domain is recursive.  Any output when it accepts is ignored.

Now, say you have a program computing a partial recursive function and you know its domain $S$ is actually recursive, because you have a *another* program that always halts and accepts on $S$, rejects outside of $S$.  Then you can make a third program that starts by running the second program to verify that the input is in $S$, and only after verifying the input is in $S$, runs the first program on the input.  This third program always halts and produces the same output as the first program on an input in $S$.

Say you have a program computing a partial recursive function.  You can modify it so that if the input is in its domain $S$ then it computes the same output and accepts, and if the input is not in its domain, it always not-halts.  How?  Just perform the same computation and if the program was going to reject, enter an infinite loop instead.

There are recursively enumerable sets that are not recursive.  This is proved with the halting problem.